# Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI.ThrowOnFailedStatusCode 404 (end point not found) on deployed bot

Tags: azure-web-app-service, botframework

I am experimenting with my first chatbot aimed to be deployed on AZURE.
For making the matter as simple as possible, I made a very simple bot.
It is a bot programmed to do just 1 thing:  print out an opening welcome message.
I want to make it as simple as possible so I can also experiment with AZURE's application insight.
It works really well on my local emulator and the webchat test on AZURE.

Yet, it failed when I tried to publish to the web by embedding the Bot's clientside interface on a webpage. AZURE's application insight throws out an HTTP error code 404.
Here is an exact copy of the error message:

POST to pilot001 failed: POST to the bot's endpoint failed with HTTP status 404
Problem Id:System.Exception at Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI.ThrowOnFailedStatusCode

Can anyone shed some light? The bot is programmed to do a simple thing: print out a welcome opening message. The returned code seems to imply that the bot couldn't find the recipient.???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strangely enough, the bot was working really well when I tested it out with my local emulator and the "test in web chat" provided by the AZURE's Bot Management.

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue... just downloaded composer, and emulator, created an emptybot and hit publish to Azure...   so no customizations, all out of the box.. same error when you try it out in webchat.